# Doubleclick on datagridview in c# open new from with 2 button like update and delete

Tags: c#

I am loading data from my database file to Datagrid. Double click on a row in datagridview in C#, open new from with 2 buttons like update and delete. If I select update, which record I selected in datagrid with that one new form should open. I am not getting idea how to do that. Here is my code for loading datagrid with a database file:

```
con.Open();
var sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM[dbo].[itemDB]", con);
var dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows) {
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["itmcode"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["brname"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["itmname"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["itmunit"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["itmgr"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["itmml"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["itmpc"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["itmtx"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["itmbyp"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["itmdlrmrg"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["itmrtmrg"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[11].Value = item["itmdlrp"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[12].Value = item["itmmrp"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[13].Value = item["itmusrcode"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[14].Value = item["active"].ToString();
}
con.Close();
```

Comment: You can do it with cell double click. Get the index of row and open the form.

Comment: Not related to the question but may help writing more compact code: you don't need to manually full a `DataGridView` with `DataTable`'s data iterating through records one by one. Just use `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` in place of the whole `foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows) {...}` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `CellDoubleClick` event's second argument has `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex` properties. Use them to identify the currently selected row and pass it to the edit form:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Assuming that the "itmcode" field uniquely identifies an itemDB table record
        var itemCode = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
        ShowEditForm(itemCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Dmitry, after doubclicking on datatable row one form of two buttons should open like edit and delete. If I click on Edit button other new form should comw with what datagrid row I selected. So here parent form -> child form-> other form.

Comment: @vijay: this is what should be implemented in `ShowEditForm` method. You may update the `DataTable` used as DataSource (see my comment to the question) from that edit form or database table and refill the `dataGridView1` depending on your requirements.

Comment: @ Dmitry, In other form i want to load datagrid row of parent form in some textboxes for edit purpose.

Comment: You may load these directly from your DB table (that's why I assumed `itmcode` is a key and passed it). Alternatively, you may pass the values from `dataGridView1` retrieving them the same way as it's shown for the `itmcode`.